# Hi Everyone, can you help me in solving a problem where my recyclerview should update automatically when data is deleted, added or updated from json

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have a problem where my code can't automatically update  every data from json changes,
the changes should happen automatically here I am using the volley library to handle them

`MainActivity` :

```
public class Gaji extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String getId;
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gaji);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        getId = user.get(sessionManager.ID);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.gaji);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.gaji:
                        break;
                    case R.id.home:
                        //Beranda
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class ));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.absen:
                        //Presensi harian
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Izin.class ));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.scan:
                        //Scan
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanQrBarcode.class ));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.profile:
                        //Profile
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class ));
                        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        parseJSON();
    }
    private void parseJSON() {
        String url = Constans.BaseUrl +"gaji.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("hasil");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit     = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String creatorName = hit.getString("gaji_pokok");
                                String asuransi    = hit.getString("asuransi");
                                String potongan    = hit.getString("potongan");
                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(creatorName, asuransi, potongan));
                            }
                            mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(Gaji.this, mExampleList);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                            mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters ke post url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id_pegawai", getId);
                return params;
            }};
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json_obj);
    }
}
```

`Adapter` :

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mContext = context;
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        String creatorName = currentItem.getCreator();
        String likeCount   = currentItem.getLikeCount();
        String potongan    = currentItem.getPotongan();
        holder.mTextViewCreator.setText("gaji pokok: " +creatorName);
        holder.mTextViewLikes.setText("asuransi: " + likeCount);
        holder.mPotongan.setText("potongan: " + potongan);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
        public TextView mTextViewLikes;
        public TextView mPotongan;
        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_creator);
            mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);
            mPotongan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_potongan);
        }
    }
}
```

`Model` :

```
public class ExampleItem {
    private String mCreator;
    private String mLikes;
    private String mPotongan;
    public ExampleItem(String creator, String likes, String potongan) {
        mCreator = creator;
        mLikes = likes;
        mPotongan = potongan;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return mCreator;
    }
    public String getLikeCount() {
        return mLikes;
    }

    public String getPotongan() {
        return mPotongan;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are re initializing adapter in parseJSON method .also clear you basic  concepts.refere below link for basics:https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/getting-to-know-recyclerview-ea14f8514e6

Answer (score 0):

You should use notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged() method from Recyclerview.Adapter class

Comment: can you help me in my code please!! I do no for your answer